# Checking if a file via stdin exists (C)

Tags: c

I'm having difficulty writing a function in C that checks whether a user inputed file (via `stdin`) exists. For instance if the program is run  as `./a.out <myfile.txt`, I want it to return false if this file does not exist. I can do this by passing the file as an argument (i.e `./a.out myfile.txt`)using `fopen()`, but not sure how to do this using 'stdin' (i.e `./a.out <myfile.txt`)

**Ok to clarify:**

The larger program is supposed to take the contents of a text file and perform actions on it. The program must be run in the command line as `./a.out arg1 arg2 <myfile.txt`. If user ran the program as `./a.out arg1 arg2` or `./a.out` (i.e not specifying the file to perform actions  on), I want to prompt the user to include a file  (using stdin `<`, not passed as an argument).

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, the shell won't run your program.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but this is part of a larger program that i'm writing and I want to print `enter a valid file` if it does not exist.

Comment: You have to check whether the file exists before trying to run the program.

Comment: On which operating system? And why? Maybe you want `isatty` to detect the case when the *stdin* is a terminal

Comment: I'm wondering if what you really want is simply to detect whether there's anything in the input. I.e. do you get an immediate EOF from stdin.

Comment: "I want to print enter a valid file if it does not exist." -- What part of "the shell won't run your program" don't you understand? Your program can't print anything if it doesn't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stdin might not be coming from a file at all. Even if it is, when the user types "< myfile.txt" at the command line, the shell swallows that part of the command, and never passes it to the program. As far as the program is concerned, it's an anonymous stream of bytes that might be from a file, a device, a terminal, a pipe, or something else. It is possible to query which of these you have, but even if you know it's a file you won't get the name of the file given on the command line, only an inode.

Comment: " creates a pipe to feed to the program" -- uh, no, the shell does not create a pipe when given "<".

Comment: "As far as the program is concerned" -- Um, look up `stat` and `ESPIPE`. Programs can generally tell what sorts of things they are reading from, and not all operations are legal on all types of input.

Comment: What you are aware of is irrelevant, since you clearly don't know much about how the shell works. *No* UNIX shell opens a pipe for "<" ... only for "|". I have done development inside the Mashey shell, the Bourne shell, and csh and I'm very familiar with how they work.

Comment: What process do you think is on the other side of that pipe providing input? You think the shell sits there feeding data to the process when it could just be reading a file? What about when it seeks? Like I said, look up ESPIPE. You obviously didn't. You think you know something but you're too lacking in knowledge to even realize what you don't know ... see "Dunning-Kruger effect".

Comment: And how about "cat foo > bar"? You think there's a pipe there too, with the shell reading from it and then writing to bar? How incredibly silly.

Comment: Whether the specifics of the answer are right are wrong, it allowed me to at least conceptually understand why I can't test if `stdin` was added at the command line the same way I can test an argument was included by checking `argc`. I instead checked the contents (not the name of the file) of `stdin` to verify if the content was included. It works fine this way, so thank you.

Comment: @InvisibleH763 I only objected to one claim in the answer (and I object to people who clearly are uninformed about the subject they are discussing arguing with people who are informed and paying no attention to what they write). At SO, it matters whether answers are incorrect (or in part incorrect) ... answers are not solely for the person who asked the question. As for verifying whether the content is valid, that's clearly the logical thing to do.

Comment: It's not Dunning-Kruger, I have no problem admitting my ignorance of shell internals; that's never been my thing. But yes, I've always assumed that the pipe() was used to do that. Obviously I was wrong. And my request to be enlightened is sincere--so how is it done? Does the subprocess inherit open file descriptors or something?

Answer (score 2):

Since the shell is responsible for opening the file for redirection, it will refuse to execute the command if the file doesn't open.

Comment: Your update is meaningless. Either data is redirected in, or it is not. Your program must decide whether or not to accept input from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Input redirection is something done by the *shell,* not your program. It simply attaches the file to standard input.

Hence, if you try to redirect input from a non-existent file, the *shell* should complain bitterly and not even *run* your program, as shown in the following transcript:

```
pax> echo hello >qq.in

pax> cat <qq.in
hello

pax> cat <nosuchfile.txt
bash: nosuchfile.txt: No such file or directory
```

In any case, your program generally doesn't *know* where the input is coming from, since you can do something like:

```
echo hello | cat
```

in which *no* file is involved.

---

If you want your program to detect the existence of a file, it will have to open the file itself, meaning you should probably give the filename as an argument rather than using standard input.

Or, you could detect the file existence *before* running your program, with something like the following `bash` segment:

```
fspec=/tmp/infile
if [[ -f ${fspec} ]] ; then
    my_prog <${fspec}
else
    echo What the ...
fi
```

Comment: @InvisibleH763 Please see the answers that you aren't reading, or aren't reading carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The OS prevent calling your program since it can provide a valid `stdin` if `myfile.txt` does not exists. You program will not run thus there is no way you can signal the file is missing, and this diagnostics is done at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

> If user ran the program as ./a.out arg1 arg2 or ./a.out (i.e not specifying the file to perform actions on), I want to prompt the user to include a file (using stdin <, not passed as an argument).

You could use OS-specific functions to check whether stdin is terminal. Checking whether it's file is a very bad idea, because it's very useful to pipe into stdin ... in fact, that's a major reason that there is such a thing as stdin in the first place. If you only want to read from a file, not a terminal or pipe, then you should take the file name as a required argument and not read from the orginal stdin (you can still read from stdin by using freopen). If you insist that you don't want to do it that way, then I will insist that you want to do it wrong.